# Nginx + jirafeau - deny acces to admin.php

Tags: linux, nginx, web, url, deny

Hello i try to deny access for externe IP to my URL admin.php of my website with nginx.

I have a jirafeau server with a example.com/admin.php
I try to deny acces for this page but dont work. I am new with nginx this is my conf :

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /admin.php;
deny all;
allow X.X.X.X/24;
}

this deny all the externe ip of my website i just need deny acces to admin.php

thx for the help!

Answer (score 1):

NGINX Short Solve:

You can use either:

- Example 1 (should work)

```
    location = /admin.php {
        deny all;
        allow 10.0.0.0/8; }
```

- Example 2 (I'm unsure if it's the proper one for this case)

```
location ~* admin.php {
        deny all;
        allow 10.0.0.0/8; }
```

- Example 3 Combined with Basic-Auth

```
    location = /admin.php {
        deny all;
        allow 10.0.0.0/8; }
        auth_basic              "restricted area";
        auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/htpw/.htpasswd;
```

- Example 4 Basic-Auth only.

```
    location = /admin.php {
        auth_basic              "restricted area";
        auth_basic_user_file    /etc/nginx/htpw/.htpasswd;
```

Remind that your Browser-Cache can tricky yourself if it's not working directly (if you didn't forgot to reload nginx, of course.)

Reference:

1. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203472/nginx-restrict-access-to-file)